# Jenkins - Mark all stages as aborted

Tags: jenkins

How to mark all stages as aborted instead of error when stopping early? I'm using `error` to stop all stages if the commit message doesn't match. But I want all the stages to be aborted instead of failed.

[image]

```
stages {    
    stage('Stage 1'){           
        steps{          
            script {
                RESULT_LOG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B')
                
                if (!RESULT_LOG.contains("[ci build]")) {
                    echo "Commit message is: ${RESULT_LOG}"
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'                                             
                    error('Stopping early…')
                } 
            }   
        }               
    }
    stage('Stage 2'){           
        steps{          
            ...
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if (!RESULT_LOG.contains("[ci build]")) {
  catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'ABORTED') {
    echo "Commit message is: ${RESULT_LOG}"                                           
    error('Stopping early…')
  }
}
```

Comment: just tested it. But it seems to run all other stages. I want all stages to abort and not continue